# Xcode7 Building Stuck at asset catalogs

Tags: xcode7, assets

Xcode6 update to Xcode7 buliding Stuck at asset catalogs 
[[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just clean(shift+cmd+alt+k) and build again.

Comment: If that fails, try deleting the project's "Derived Data".

Comment: I have try, but it's still stuck on that

Answer (score 0):

If you have many image set's in the Assets.xcassets folder, It is taking more time to compile all the image sets. I tried restarting the xcode, cleaning the build folder, cleaning the derived data, restarting the mac, nothing works.

I just simply waited with patience, xcode takes it own time to compile it and the build is getting success.

This happened for me in Xcode 9.3